# How do I efficiently collapse a column by a substring it contains?

Tags: python, regex, string, bigdata

I have a dataset that looks like:

| Type | Count |
| --- | --- |
| Customer Operations | 900 |
| Direct Sales | 100 |
| Customer Connections | 200 |
| Sales - Route | 100 |

and I basically want to aggregate it based on the substring it contains, here "Customer" and "Sales"

| Type | Count |
| --- | --- |
| Customer | 1100 |
| Sales | 200 |

I know I can use both a `in` string function or capturing groups in Regex, but my dataset is very large and I wanted a very efficient way to do this. Any ideas?

Comment: Perhaps you could provide an example that does work on your example data (albeit slowly for large datasets) and we might be able to suggest ways of speeding it up? If you get any helpful answers, look at [someone answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```py
print(
    df.groupby(df["Type"].str.extract(r"(?P<Type>Customer|Sales)")["Type"])
    .sum()
    .reset_index()
)
```

Prints:

```
       Type  Count
0  Customer   1100
1     Sales    200
```